# Get generic type for java.util.Map parameter

Tags: java, generics, reflection, dictionary

```
public Object[] convertTo(Map source, Object[] destination) {
    ...
}
```

Is there a possibility to figure out the generic types (key / value) of my Map parameter via Reflection?

Comment: Why would you want to do that? That is the purpose of that method?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question, but I think the answer might be in the code for [Collection.toArray()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray%28T[]%29).

Comment: Your actual map doesn't have generic types, it currently maps `Object` to `Object`.

Comment: It is possible, but only if the Map is subclassed/subtyped. See [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) for an example.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Given a `Map<Key,Value>`, it isn't possible to figure out `Key` and `Value` at runtime. This is due to [type erasure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) (also, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Type_erasure)).

It is, however, possible to examine each object (key or value) contained in the map, and call their [`getClass()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass%28%29) method. This will tell you the runtime type *of that object*. Note that this still won't tell you anything about the compile-type types `Key` and `Value`.

Comment: *Of course* it doesn't work if the map is empty an *of course* it gives wrong results if the generic types are either interfaces or abstract classes...

Comment: It actually is possible if the Map is subclassed, ex, `StringMap extends Map<String, String> { ...`. Check out [TypeTools](https://github.com/jhalterman/typetools) for an example of how to extract the type args.

Answer (score 24):

I know this question is old, but the best answer is wrong.
You can easily get the generic types via reflections. Here an example:

```
private Map<String, Integer> genericTestMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        Field testMap = Test.class.getDeclaredField("genericTestMap");
        testMap.setAccessible(true);

        ParameterizedType type = (ParameterizedType) testMap.getGenericType();

        Type key = type.getActualTypeArguments()[0];

        System.out.println("Key: " + key);

        Type value = type.getActualTypeArguments()[1];

        System.out.println("Value: " + value);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This will get you the output:
`Key: class java.lang.String`
`Value: class java.lang.Integer`

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. You are retrieving the generic type of the declaration. This is not the same problem as retrieving the compile-time generic type of an object instance for which the generic type information has been erased. Specifically the OP typed the Map parameter without any generic parameters (implicitly <Object,Object>) from which this information could be recovered. Your answer, while useful for your specific case, does not address the question.

Comment: @Sergio - it is not the accepted answer for a reason

Comment: The accepted answer might be correctly answering the stated question, but this answer does help solving some issues where the accepted answer did not. So thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the Class for entries in the source object by getting each element, and calling getClass on the key/value object for each. Of course, if the map wasn't genericised at source then there's no guarantee that all the keys/values in it are of the same type.

Comment: Hi! Yes, that could work.. But I also have the reverse method, where I have to convert from Object[] to Map. And there I can't use this approach.

Comment: *Of course* it doesn't work if the map is empty an *of course* it gives wrong results if the generic types are either interfaces or abstract classes...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the value type from the map at run-time, but maybe you can get it from the `destination` array (as long as it is not `null`.)

```
public <V> V[] convertTo(Map<?,V> source, V[] destination) {
    return source.values().toArray(destination);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this way you can get the type of the key and value of a map

```
public class Demo 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Map map = new HashMap<String, Long>();
        map.put("1$", new Long(10));
        map.put("2$", new Long(20));
        Set<?> set = map.entrySet();
        Iterator<?> iterator = set.iterator();
        String valueClassType="";
        while (iterator.hasNext()) 
        {
            Map.Entry entry = (Entry) iterator.next();
            valueClassType = entry.getValue().getClass().getSimpleName();
            System.out.println("key type : "+entry.getKey().getClass().getSimpleName());
            System.out.println("value type : "+valueClassType);
        }
    }
}
```